# Special Character Truncating Database Value

Tags: mysql, swift, utf-8

I have a string value that I am trying to insert into a field (Type: Varchar(255) Collation: utf8_general_ci). In my PHP file, I've included `mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8")`. In my Swift file I included `request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)`. But when I browse the database table, the inserted string value is always truncated specifically before the character '&'. What more can I do to fix this?

Comment: In mysql cli browsing this is AFAIK not possible to prevent. Use a different browsing method like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench to view your data instead since those tools take those kind of scenarios better into account.

Comment: I already am using phpMyAdmin

Comment: Ok, try mysql workbench since apparently phpMyAdmin is faulty at this point too

Comment: I just made the switch to MySQLWorkBench and it seems I'm having the same issue as previously stated. Do you think it could be something with the Swift file?

Comment: HUm then it might not end up in your database: Make a dump of the table with mysqldump to check (That really exports everything all the time every time).

Comment: Let's check the data:  `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` for some non-English character.

Comment: Do not use the deprecated `mysql_*` interface; switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.